# What are the other "codes" for the left and right keys in python?

Tags: python, key, arrow-keys

```
while True:
    key = ord(getch())  

    if key == 72:
        print "up"
        time.sleep(1)

    elif key == 80:
        print "down."
        time.sleep(1)
```

I am searching for same kind of codes for arrow keys.

What are the codes for LEFT and RIGHT?

Comment: Is that your complete program? Cause on my Python installation, all I get is `NameError: name 'getch' is not defined`.

Comment: Where is this `getch` coming from? My answer assumed it's from the `msvcrt` module, meaning that you're on Windows, but your question is not tagged Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are calling the [_getch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) function which is provided in the `msvcrt` module on Windows platforms.

Note that the arrow keys are delivered as *two* values, that is, your values for UP and DOWN are wrong (alone, 72 is 'H' and 80 is 'P').

By complementing the documentation above with experimentation it seems like the answer may be:

- UP is either 0 or 224, followed by 72.
- DOWN is either 0 or 224, followed by 80.
- LEFT is either 0 or 224, followed by 75.
- RIGHT is either 0 or 224, followed by 77.

First call `_getch` once, and if it's either 0 or 224, call it again to get the actual key codes for the arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    key = ord(getch()) 
    print(key)
```

and then press the keys you want to know.